# is it possible to spawn a new ec2 instance by attaching an old already existing ebs as root volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i want to launch a new ec2-instance but instead of having a blank ebs , I want an existing ebs volume should be used as root volume for the new machine that is coming up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: not sure if possible, but will probably be easier to snapshot it and make an bootable AMI from the snapshot

Comment: @BretzL 
I considered that process, it takes substantial time.Especially snapshot creation if ebs size is large. 
(Total time= Time for (snapshot creation + AMI creation + launching instance from AMI))

whereas, if we launch  a particular AMI  using a particular EBS as root, would be  much faster

Comment: You can detach root volumes only when the instance is stopped and during instance creation can only attach additional volumes from snapshots. You could create a new instance from the same AMI, stop it and swap out the root EBS. Not sure if it will be much faster. If you only need the data from the old root volume you can attach it after the new instance started and mount the folders you need.